# read README in setup.py

Tags: python, setuptools, distutils, setup.py

So, I want the `long_description` of my setup script to be the contents from my `README.md` file. But when I do this, the installation of the source distribution will fail since `python setup.py sdist` does not copy the readme file.

Is there a way to let `distutils.core.setup()` include the `README.md` file with the `sdist` command so that the installation will not fail?

I have tried a little workaround where I default to some shorter text when the `README.md` file is not available, but I actually do want that not only PyPi gets the contents of the readme file but also the user that installs the package.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To manually include files in a distribution do the following:

1. set `include_package_data = True`
2. Create a MANIFEST.in file that has a list of `include <glob>` lines for each file you want to include from the project root. You can use `recursive-include <dirname> <glob>` to include from sub-directories of the project root.

Unfortunately the documentation for this stuff is really fragmented and split across the Python distutils, setuptools, and old distribute docs so it can be hard to figure out what you need to do.

Comment: that worked for me too though I just used point 2 (point 1 seems redundant)

Comment: The doc is not fragmented anymore if you use setuptools, which is the defacto packaging standard right now. See here: http://pythonhosted.org//setuptools/setuptools.html#including-data-files

Comment: @Marconius moved to here: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html?highlight=data%20files#including-data-files

Comment: I would recommend ignoring `1.` as it would include `.pyc` files too.