# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'readme.md'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, package

Im trying to install ghasedak package via pip which i have done before but now it raises this error.

```
(venv) hamed@hamed-HP-250-G6-Notebook-PC:~/sqh-source$ pip3 install ghasedak  --upgrade
Collecting ghasedak
  Using cached ghasedak-0.1.8.tar.gz (2.0 kB)
    ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: /home/hamed/sqh-source/venv/bin/python -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vb0m4x9b/ghasedak/setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'/tmp/pip-install-vb0m4x9b/ghasedak/setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' egg_info --egg-base /tmp/pip-install-vb0m4x9b/ghasedak/pip-egg-info
         cwd: /tmp/pip-install-vb0m4x9b/ghasedak/
    Complete output (5 lines):
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-vb0m4x9b/ghasedak/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        with open("readme.md", "r") as fh:
    FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'readme.md'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: python setup.py egg_info Check the logs for full command output.
```

After a lot of search i found someone said i have to make MANIFEST.in but where should i place it and someone said we dont need that then finally is it right to use it or is there any other solution?

Comment: You may wish to report this packaging issue at the [package's issue tracker](https://github.com/ghasedakapi/ghasedak-python/issues).  The package's `setup.py` specified the `readme.md` file, but it was not packaged in the [tarball provided on pypi](https://pypi.org/project/ghasedak/#files).  If you are in fact the package maintainer, you may wish to refer to [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23174516/read-readme-in-setup-py) to correct the issue.

Comment: I was able to repro, and created an issue https://github.com/ghasedakapi/ghasedak-python/issues/5

Comment: The maintainer suggested `pip install --upgrade pip` and then retrying. This fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

My problem didnt solve so I downloaded ghasedak from github with the below command
pip install git+https://github.com/package-url/